# C float from binary

Tags: c, floating-point

I am tryling to learn C and now i am a floats. I know all values have different sizes on different machines. But i am trying to learn the concept.

Lets say a float is saved in 4 bytes. I read that the first bit is the sign bit, which decide if the number is positve or negative. Then the next 7 bits is the exponent and the rest (23 bits) is the mantissa. Which could be this:
1 010 1001 0000 0000 1011 1001 0000 111

But how does this translate to a float? I can read binary but i dont see the formula behind it :). Could some one explain this one to me, or how it works?

Comment: Not sure how long this question will stay afloat.

Comment: Classic paper on the subject [what every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this a few years ago.
I think it should help you understand how floating point numbers are represented:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/float/

Basically, the formula for normalized numbers is:  **`-1^S * 1.M * 2^( E - 127 )`** where **S** is the sign, **M** the mantissa, and **E** the exponent. But everything is explained in details in the previous link.

Comment: Thank you! The only part where i am a little bit stuck is this: quote from your article you go from this -10 · 1.0111 · 22 to this
Mathematically, this means:
1 · ( 1 · 20 + 0 · 2-1 + 1 · 2-2 + 1 · 2-3 + 1 · 2-4 ) · 22
( 20 + 2-2 + 2-3 + 2-4 ) · 22
22 + 20 + 2-1 + 2-2
4 + 1 + 0.5 + 0.25

Comment: Guess my math isn't that good to make that jump without some hints

Comment: The mantissa is expressed as binary scientific notation, so this is the computation of the real value. As for a normal binary number, the formula is: `( bit_1_value * 2 ^ bit_1_position ) + ( bit_2_value * 2 ^ bit_2_position ) + ...`. But as this is scientific notation, and as we have a comma, the bit position value is decremented, hence the -1, -2, etc.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of reading. Your article said it all i just read it like a rtard. =) Thank you again

Comment: No worries : ) Nice to know the article was helpful.

Comment: Please note that “significand” is a better term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation than “mantissa”. A “mantissa” is the fractional portion of a logarithm. The fraction portion of a floating-point number is linear, not logarithmic. The IEEE 754 standard uses “significand”.

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 bits in the exponent:
seee eeee emmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm mmmm

The formula is:
(-1)^s * 1.M * 2^(E - 127)

I used big M and E to represent all the m and e bits, respectively. The M part is binary, the E part is decimal.